# Problem Bigquery stored procedure not filtering

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use a stored procedure to get some data from my clients filtering a table by date and channel of purchase in a query that looks something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `sandbox.clients.dateandchannel`
    (IN DT DATE, 
     IN CH STRING)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        client_id,
        purchase_id,
        purchase_date,
        channel
    FROM 
        `trusted-zone.clients_purchases`
    WHERE 
        channel = CH
        AND purchase_date = DT;
END
```

After running the procedure, I use the following call:

```
CALL `sandbox.clients.dateandchannel`('2021-09-11','Ecommerce');
```

The call executes and returns a table, but the result is never filtered.

The dates don't correspond to '2021-09-11' and the channel doesn't correspond to 'Ecommerce'

I can't understand if it is a problem with the query, or if I am doing something conceptually wrong but would love if someone had a clue to why this is happening.

Also the next step for me would be to extract the resulting table to a temp table or such to use this result in other steps of multiple queries. Inside a with, for example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use a view if you want to reuse the result in a query?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, that is a good question. This is just a first preliminar test for a whole set of other procedures i would like to create. But , to answer your question, i went with procedures so i can pass specific parameters to it.

Comment: query looks good to me! i tried to reproduce your case and did all as you described above - but it really perfectly worked for me! so you should look into data itself and try to narrow down the problem

Comment: Agree, I spent time to bend the query to reproduce your case, and impossible...

Comment: Hello people, im sorry it took me so long to answer. I seem to have found the problem. I was using an unclosed OR clause that was causing me the filtering problem and i failed to represent that in my example mentioned above. I already managed to get the result correctly filtered and to get it out of the call through a TEMP TABLE that i can use inside other queries. Thanks a lot anyway for your support.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you go back from the basics, from the semantic:

- Procedure execute code and return nothing, except the parameter in OUT mode
- Function execute code and return something.

So, the procedure will never send you back results, by design, by semantic!

---

If you need to pass parameter to something and to get a resultSet as answer you need a Functions. The [table functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/table-functions) are made for that!

Comment: Thanks for the response Guillaume. As may be evident to you, im not a DB expert. So i understand i am not using the best option to do what i want. But can you explain a bit more why it's not possible? It's still not quite clear to me. Is my problem not having an out variable? is it because i can't get a table out of a stored procedure? Is my CALL function written wrong somehow? Because the thing is: i do get a table in return from my call, with the exact same columns i input in the procedure, but the values i get back have not been filtered in the WHERE clause. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: My bad!! I answered your "next step" question and I forgot the core of your issue!